# Should I discuss the content of pending project proposals in faculty interview?

Tags: interview, research-proposal

stackexchange community,

I will be having a faculty interview in the coming weeks and I am currently working on my presentation for the interview day, which should, according to their instructions, focus on my current research activities.

In it, I have included some details on a planned project that I have already submitted for approval to a funding agency. The idea in the proposal is very novel and it would form an important contribution in our field. Note that the application process did not require a research proposal to be submitted.

However, I have started thinking now whether that is a good idea... In the evaluation committee there will be many researchers that are in the same field as I am. Now, if I end up not getting the position and my proposal is not funded either, do I run the risk of giving my novel idea away "for free"? I would want to include it in my presentation though, as it would show that I already have further future plans to build on my current work and make more contributions...

Is that a reasonable concern from my side or should I not worry and choose to believe in the academic integrity of the committee? Is there some middle road or some work-around that I could use?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd tend to do it. You have already submitted it, so there's some kind of written proof that it's yours. Stealing research ideas happens, but in my experience it happens very rarely. Ultimately it depends on a number of factors:

1. How much better do you think explaining this project would make your presentation? It can be very valuable showing your insight, but if you have lots of other stuff it may not be that important.
2. What do you know about the interview panel and the faculty? Any reasons not to trust them? If it's a small panel it seems very unlikely that some of the panelists would do such a thing.
3. Apart from the funding application itself, do you have anything else already out in the open (preprints, conference presentations etc.) that testifies that this is your idea?
4. How difficult would it be to make something out of the idea with just the information you give in the presentation? Obviously you can to some extent lower this probability by being selective about how exactly you explain it.

All that said, personally I'd not be very worried about this possibility. I don't think I know of ideas that were nicked in such a situation. There's no such thing as 100% safety though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! To briefly respond to your questions, 1. it would be valuable, yes, 2. I do not have reasons to not trust them and we are a small community in this country, 3. I unfortunately do not, as the idea was rather new and we packaged it immediately to a project proposal, 4. I of course leave crucial details out, but theoretically one could embark from what I present and try to reproduce it.

Overall, I think you are right and I should not worry too much. Technically, research plans submitted as parts of applications also run the same risk, but nothing ever happens...